# Error message: !LaTeX Error: File `etoolbox.sty` not found

Tags: tables, errors

I saw this table on another post. I would like to mimic it. I get an error message when trying to compile the code.

```
The required file `tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty` is missing. It is part of the package `etoolbox`.
!LaTeX Error: File `etoolbox.sty` not found.
```

When I ignore the error, I get an error that stops the compilation:

```
`Undefined control sequence \newtoggle`.
```

Do I need the packages `siunitx` and `adjustbox`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}\setstackEOL{\cr} %EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5in}
\textbf{16.) }\raggedright{The table shows certain function values of \textit{f}. \\If $g(x) = f(3x + 1)$, what is the value of $g(2)$?}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }$-5$ \\
\> \textbf{b.) }$-1$ \\
\> \textbf{c.) }0 \\
\> \textbf{d.) }2 \\
\> \textbf{e.) }4
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.75cm}
%
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\belowbaseline[-7pt]{\stackunder{\bfseries\Longstack{Certain Function\cr Values of \textit{f}}{%
\begin{tabular}{|| c | S[table-format=-1.0] ||} \hline
    \textit{x}  &   {$f(x)$} \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
    2           &   -1 \\ \hline
    3           &   0 \\ \hline
    4           &   2 \\ \hline
    5           &   -3 \\ \hline
    6           &   4 \\ \hline
    7           &   -5 \\ \hline
    8           &   6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, you should install `etoolbox` then. And you're using `S` columntypes, so yes, you need `siunitx`

Comment: I hit `Install` and get the following two error messages.

Comment: `!LaTeX Error: File etoolbox.sty not found.`

Comment: `Type X to quit or <Return> to proceed or enter new  name. (Default extension: sty)`

Comment: Perhaps your editor or something else is disturbing the on-the-fly installation. Use the package manager to install etoolbox and the other missing packages.

Comment: @user74973: The three comments about the errors are not really useful

Comment: @Christian Hupfer My computer has not been able to install `etoolbox`. I have brought it to a technician and have been told that my version of MikTeX needs to install many updates ... and that my computer needs maintenance. That may explain `etoolbox` did not install when I hit `Install`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basically about an error when installing a package on an outdated installation.